# Julia: How to return the number of unique elements in an Array

Tags: julia

What's the function to return the number of unique elements in an Array in Julia?

In R you have `length(unique(x))`. I can do the same in Julia but there should be a more efficient way I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want an exact answer `length(unique(x))` is as efficient as it gets for general objects. If your values have a limited domain, eg `UInt8`, it may be more efficient to use a fixed size table. If you can accept an approximation, then you can use the HyperLogLog data structure / algorithm, which is implemented in the OnlineStats package:

https://joshday.github.io/OnlineStats.jl/latest/api/#OnlineStats.HyperLogLog

Comment: How well does `length(unique(x))` scale? Does it ultimately use `Set(x)` as suggested by @Cameron Bieganek

Answer (score 7):

It appears that `length(Set(x))` is somewhat faster than `length(unique(x))`.

```
julia> using StatsBase, BenchmarkTools

julia> num_unique(x) = length(Set(x));

julia> a = sample(1:100, 200);

julia> num_unique(x) == length(unique(x))
true

julia> @benchmark length(unique(x)) setup=(x = sample(1:10000, 20000))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  450.50 KiB
  allocs estimate:  36
  --------------
  minimum time:     498.130 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      570.588 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        579.011 μs (2.41% GC)
  maximum time:     2.321 ms (63.03% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          5264
  evals/sample:     1

julia> @benchmark num_unique(x) setup=(x = sample(1:10000, 20000))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  288.68 KiB
  allocs estimate:  8
  --------------
  minimum time:     283.031 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      393.317 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        397.878 μs (4.24% GC)
  maximum time:     33.499 ms (98.80% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          6704
  evals/sample:     1
```

And another benchmark for an array of strings:

```
julia> using Random

julia> @benchmark length(unique(x)) setup=(x = [randstring(3) for _ in 1:10000])
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  450.50 KiB
  allocs estimate:  36
  --------------
  minimum time:     818.024 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      895.944 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        906.568 μs (1.61% GC)
  maximum time:     1.964 ms (51.19% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          3049
  evals/sample:     1

julia> @benchmark num_unique(x) setup=(x = [randstring(3) for _ in 1:10000])
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  144.68 KiB
  allocs estimate:  8
  --------------
  minimum time:     367.018 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      378.666 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        384.486 μs (1.07% GC)
  maximum time:     1.314 ms (70.80% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          4527
  evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: Nice one!, It seems that, the fastest non-mutating method to count the unique values of an array is `length(Set(x))` for a lot of types

Comment: Interesting results. I wonder why `unique` needs so many more allocations than `Set`?

Answer (score 4):

if you don't need the x array after, `length(unique!(x))` is slightly faster.
with Floats and Integers, you can use map reduce if your array is already sorted.

```
function count_unique_sorted(x)
    f(a) = (a,0)
    function op(a,b)
    if a[1] == b[1]
        return (b[1],a[2])
    else
        return (b[1],a[2]+1)
    end
    end
    return mapreduce(f,op,x)[2]+1 
end
```

If you don't care about the order of the array `x`, you can sort and count in one function:

```
count_unique_sorted!(x)=count_unique_sorted(sort!(x))
```

Some benchmarks:

```
using Random,StatsBase, BenchmarkTools
x  = sample(1:100,200)
length(unique(x)) == count_unique_sorted(sort(x)) #true
```

Using `length(unique(x))`:

```
@benchmark length(unique(x))
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  6.08 KiB
  allocs estimate:  17
  --------------
  minimum time:     3.350 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      3.688 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        5.352 μs (24.35% GC)
  maximum time:     6.691 ms (99.90% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     8
```

Using `Set`:

```
@benchmark length(Set(x))
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  2.82 KiB
  allocs estimate:  8
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.256 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.467 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        3.654 μs (26.04% GC)
  maximum time:     5.297 ms (99.91% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     9
```

Using `count_unique_sorted!`:

```
x2 = copy(x)
@benchmark count_unique_sorted!(x2)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     948.387 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      990.323 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.038 μs (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     2.481 μs (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     31
```

Using `count_unique_sorted` with an already sorted array

```
x3 = sort(x)
@benchmark count_unique_sorted(x3)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     140.962 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      146.831 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        154.121 ns (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     381.806 ns (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     852
```

Using `count_unique_sorted` and sorting the array

```
@benchmark count_unique_sorted(sort(x))
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  1.77 KiB
  allocs estimate:  1
  --------------
  minimum time:     1.470 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.630 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.367 μs (21.82% GC)
  maximum time:     4.880 ms (99.94% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     10
```

For strings, sorting and counting is slower than making a Set.

Comment: Your benchmark for `count_unique_sorted!` is not accurate, because in the first evaluation `x` gets sorted, and then for every subsequent evaluation `x` is already sorted. Also, using a longer vector makes the cost of having to pre-sort more apparent. Compare `x = sample(1:10_000, 20_000); @benchmark count_unique_sorted!(x)` to `@benchmark count_unique_sorted!(x) setup=(x = sample(1:10_000, 20_000))`. The median run time is about 5x longer when you use the `setup` argument to provide a new unsorted vector for each evaluation.